# Snowflake Querying Nested JSON stored as an Array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I’ve run the following code to produce an array in a table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PROVIDER_TABLE_V8 AS 
SELECT "rmpostcode", 
array_agg(object_delete(object_construct(f.*),'rmpostcode') ) within group (order by "name") AS "providers"
FROM FASTEST_DOWN_STR_V8 f
GROUP BY "rmpostcode";
```

I’m now trying to check the resulting table has done what I think it has... but I’m not sure how to query the resulting object. Trying lateral flatten and so on fails because it’s not JSON anymore, is it?

EDIT: Thanks @Rob Silva, I've changed the datatype to `VARIANT` which helped a little in the creation of this table.

The object I have is

`[    {      "fastest_down": "0.00",      "name": "B4RN",      "present": "0"    },    {      "fastest_down": "0.00",      "name": "Gigaclear",      "present": "0"    },    {      "fastest_down": "0.00",      "name": "OFNL (IFNL)",      "present": "0"    },    {      "fastest_down": "0.00",      "name": "airband_fibre",      "present": "0"    },    {      "fastest_down": "0.00",      "name": "balquhidder",      "present": "0"    },    {      "fastest_down": "0.00",      "name": "blackfibre",      "present": "0"    }, ...]`

That is one row.

What I'm trying to do is find all rows for which `present = 1` for a specified `name`, but I'm struggling to query the nested JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying lateral flatten and so on fails because it’s not JSON anymore,
> is it?

It is. You can take it over to jsonlint.com and it validates.

Here's a breakdown of how to get this working step by step:

```
create table foo (v variant);

-- Insert your data
insert into foo select parse_json('<your json>');

-- See how it looks raw.
select * from foo;

-- Now flatten the array with a lateral join.
-- Note the addition of metadata columns from the
-- output of the flatten table function
select * from foo, lateral flatten(v);

-- Filter rows to where present = 1
-- Parse using the pattern COLUMN_NAME:json_property::cast_type
select * from foo, lateral flatten(v) where VALUE:present::int = 1;

-- Clean up and alias the names, etc.
select   VALUE:fastest_down::float      as FASTEST_DOWN
        ,VALUE:name::string             as "NAME"
        ,VALUE:present::int             as PRESENT
from   foo, lateral flatten(v)
-- Optionally add your where clause on PRESENT
;
```

Comment: Thanks @Greg, it is a tricky function to get your head around at first, but managed to get this working

Comment: Personally i think the problem with OP case was that array_agg creates array type, where snowflake expects object or variant or text for parse_json. 
::variant should be good cast to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Chris - try using parse_json(providers) and see if the resulting object can be flattened the way you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not - I run SELECT parse_json("providers") FROM "UPC"."DEV"."PROVIDER_TABLE_V8" LIMIT 10; but I get the error

SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 Invalid argument types for function 'PARSE_JSON': (ARRAY)

Comment: In the example you've added you have multiple `present` in the same row.

You mean at least one `present = 1` in the row, or that the `name` is part of the "input"?

Comment: yes sorry I should have put the original table but it's "rmpostcode","name","fastest down","present"